# How can I load service dependencies into model classes?

Tags: dependency-injection, service-locator

My model objects are generated by the library using hard-wired new operators, which makes dependencies injection using the constructor impossible. However, they also have methods, which are called by the library (i.e. adding service objects as parameter is not an option), using external service objects for the logic.

Is using the service locator anti-pattern the only option here?

Comment: I had this same issue with creating Roslyn code analysers for C#. Roslyn requires an analyser class inherit from a base class and that it be created via a parameterless constructor. So the service locator anti-pattern was the only way to expose dependencies to these analysers. It's crap, but sometimes poor design choices by others forces you to use poor designs yourself.

Comment: @Davidarno and Michael, could either of you please explain how you plan to solve hard-wired dependencies using service locator?  Are you describing a refactoring to add calls to a service locator to existing classes or creating new classes that call the service locator?  This is a trick I'd like to see.

Comment: My model logic requires some external dependencies (e.g. public key serializer, storage driver) to work, but it does not allow dependency injection via the constructor, so I override the default constructor to load the dependencies from a service locator and provide getter/setters to change the dependencies.